# Delete boot files that appear to BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

Hello guys and thanks for opening the question at least

I need help I installed so much OS (at least 15) before but I didn't Delete them by true way and the boot files of all of them is appears to my BIOS and my BIOS has bug and when my Boot files goes more than 12 it's crushing (this bug appears after I update the BIOS to latest version) and now I wanna delete that Boot files that appear in BIOS.

I installed all of them with windows 10 dual boot

Can anybody help? **:*(***

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I searched the internet for the easiest way to delete them and this is the best way to delete them by windows command prompt and it works for me:

https://www.binaryera.com/2020/08/RemoveGrubFromWindow10.html

Just follow the steps on this site.

> 1. Type Windows Key + R to open Run box and type `cmd` inside it.
> 2. Type `diskpart` in a cmd window and click yes when prompted.
> 3. This will open a new window.
> 4. Type command `list vol` . This will show you all the disk volumes. One of these will be EFI/System volume. It will always in FAT32
>    format.
> 5. Select the volume by `Select Volume X` command where `X` will be replaced by volume number or EFI/System volume.
> 6. Assign the letter to volume using `Assign Letter=X` command, where `X` will be replaced by any letter. For convenience I'm assigning the letter
>    Z. Type `Exit` command to close the window after assigning the letter.
> 7. Open command prompt as an administrator. If prompted press Yes.
> 8. Type `Z:` command to access the EFI drive.
> 9. Type the command `dir` to find the directory inside the drive.
> 10. Type `cd EFI` command to change directories to the EFI directory.
> 11. Type `dir` to view the directory inside. There will be more than two directories. One directory will be Microsoft, the second will be Boot,
>     and the third will be the OS directory that was uninstalled. It may be
>     Ubuntu if you uninstalled Ubuntu.
> 12. Run the `rmdir /s OSNAME` command, where OSNAME will be replaced by your OSNAME, to delete the GRUB bootloader from your computer. If
>     prompted press Y.
> 13. Exit the command prompt and restart the computer. The GRUB bootloader will no longer be available.

Comment: The only thing that I don't know about it is the "UOS" in my Boot options ad I don't know do I should delete it or not If you guys knows any thing about this pleases tell me

Comment: OK thanks you and thanks @karel for editing this answer